# How to handle calculations on huge numpy array to avoid memory allocation error?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need a negative identity matrix of size (62500 x 62500). 
declaring a normal identity matrix using numpy works like a charm:

```
eye = np.eye(62500, 62500)
```

However, doing something like this

```
negative_eye1 = np.negative(np.eye(62500, 62500))
# or
negative_eye2 = np.eye(62500, 62500) * -1
```

will result in this error

> Unable to allocate array with shape (62500, 62500) and data type float64

The matrix is then used in a `scipy.sparse.bmat()` function, resulting in a csr-matrix, where memory won't be such an issue anymore.

How can I calculate this matrix?

Comment: Did you try: `x = np.diag(np.full((6250), -1))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy.sparse.eye](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.eye.html) (sparse matrix with ones on diagonal):

```
from scipy import sparse

negative_eye = -sparse.eye(62500, 62500)
```